# bash arguments with quotes in script

Tags: bash, quotes

I'm trying to construct a (complicated) call to a program in bash.

The program expects a list of files, where file names could potentially contain spaces.

I construct the call as follows:

```
for VAR in $ARR; do
    CALL_ARGS+=" \"${VAR}.csv\""
done
```

and then call the program with `./program ${CALL_ARGS}`

When `$VAR` is `"a b c"` for instance, I would like to have `./program "a b c"`, but what I get is `'"a' b 'c.csv"'` which is obviously wrongly quoted.

I've seen some similar questions/answers on StackOverflow already, but none seem to be applicable to my problem.

Comment: Is the list of files passed as separate arguments to your script? Then simply use `./program "$@"` which does the right thing.

Comment: No, it's not. I construct the list, by calling a lot of different programs.

Comment: Can you add them to the positional parameters one-by-one with `set -- "$@" "$file"`?

Comment: Storing lists in plain variables never works right; use arrays instead. See [this previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432352/list-of-arguments-in-only-one-variable-in-bash) for an example of dynamically generating  an arg list, and [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for general info. BTW, you have this problem with both `$ARR` (which doesn't appear to be an array) and `$CALL_ARGS`, and you need to fix *both* before it'll work right. Oh, and avoid the temptation to use `eval` -- that way lies madness and truly bizarre bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and safest way to handle lists of items that may contain spaces (or various other characters) in Bash is to use arrays.  For example:

```
files=('a b c' 'd e' f)
args=()

for f in "${files[@]}" ; do
    args+=( "$f".csv )
done

./program "${args[@]}"
```